# How to find out farthest north south east and west coordinates of a polygon?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, coordinates

I have hundreds of employees spread around the country. I need them to fill a form and they need to fill a mandatory decimal coordinates field.

They often write wrong coordinates that end up in the sea or neighbour countries and that messes up my analysis.

I want to write an Excel formula that prevents them from entering GPS coordinates that are not in the area of their responsiblity. In order to do that, I need to know the farthest north, south, east and west coordinates of a polygon, for example their city, province or village in ArcMap.

Could you please tell me how or point me to right direction?

Comment: Knowing bounding box coordinates is not enough. You have to estimate if point sits inside relevant polygon .

Comment: @FelixIP Yes, that would force them to give the exact right coordinates.  But I think that would complicate things way too much. I am not sure if I can do that, both in Arcmap and Excel.

Comment: one common mistake with untrained staff is entering the minute as if they were decimal values (e.g. 5'59° -> 5.59 ) Because GPS can usually project the coordinates on the fly, those errors can be avoided by asking to fill in XY coordinates.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This is called the bounding box coordinates. You can get those using the field calculator.

For instance, add a new field, right click on the field, launch "calculate field" and enter the following line of code (after checking "Python")

```
!Shape!.extent.XMin
```

you can also use XMax, YMax, and YMin for the other values.